# SQL: Getting previous record from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the previous record of each record in Table A from Table B.

[image]

for easy, below is the table sample data:

```
drop table if exists #A
drop table if exists #B


CREATE TABLE #A(Name varchar(10), time datetime, value int)
insert into #A values
('A', '2020-03-31 18:00:00', 56),
('A', '2020-03-31 19:00:00', 3),
('B', '2020-03-31 14:00:00', 14),
('C', '2020-03-31 15:00:00', 26)


CREATE TABLE #B(Name varchar(10), time datetime, value int)
insert into #A values
('A', '2020-03-31 21:00:00', 79),
('A', '2020-03-31 17:00:00', 44),
('A', '2020-03-31 14:00:00', 76),
('B', '2020-03-31 18:00:00', 89),
('C', '2020-03-31 11:00:00', 29),
('C', '2020-03-31 08:00:00', 6)
```

**EDIT:**
It should include only last previous record from TableB.
Sorry for the confusion. Changed image and sample data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select a.name, a.time, a.value
from #a a
union all
select b.name, b.time, b.value
from (select b.*, row_number() over (order by time desc) as seqnum
      from #b b
      where b.time < (select min(a.time)
                      from #a a
                      where a.name = b.name
                     )
     ) b
where seqnum = 1
order by name, time;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=513e06b60f838f3a536602328a9b9025) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If `b` could have multiple "previous" records, then:

```
select a.name, a.time, a.value
from #a a
union all
select b.name, b.time, b.value
from (select b.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by b.name order by b.time desc) as seqnum
      from #b b
      where b.time < (select min(a.time)
                      from #a a
                      where a.name = b.name
                     )
     ) b
where seqnum = 1
order by name, time;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57e710c6a68394f9aa2e44d3211ede15) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will it be efficient if Table B has around 1 million records and growing, and Table A will have around 2000 records? Thanks for the solution

Comment: @user1041627 . . . You don't really have much choice.  But with an index on `b(name, time)`, performance should be fine.

Comment: Hi Gordon, one issue: I want only one previous record, whereas this one is returning all previous record of each name. e.g if [A - 17:00] is perfect but it also returns is [A-16:00] and all it's previous.

Comment: @user1041627 . . . I needed to fix the answer anyway, because you want the latest record from `b`, not the earliest.

Comment: @user1041627 . . . My edits didn't seem to go in.  The version there now seems to work.